# Rails Active Record Seems to Be Broken, Rails 4.0.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

O.k. this is driving me crazy - if anyone could help that would be great.

I have a simple table "threads" with an auto id and a "name" field with one record (id = 1, name = "space").

I have a model named "Thread.rb".

```
class Thread < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

I have a controller that calls:

```
@thread = Thread.find_by_id(1)
```

But when loading a page I get the following error in the controller:

```
undefined method `find_by_id' for Thread:Class
```

I've used find_by_sql numerous times in the same project with no problem, but when using the simple activerecord accessors rails errors out on "find", "find_by_id" etc.

I'm on rails 4.0.2

Comment: try using `@thread = Thread.find(1)`. Also here is a useful link for activerecord finder methods: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html

Comment: Yep, I did. For some reason I think rails isn't seeing my Threads class. Yet I can't even use find_by_sql on the threads model either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm pretty sure `Thread` is a reserved word in Rails, I recall having the same issue. Renaming your class should solve it. I was able to find [this community authored site](http://reservedwords.herokuapp.com/words) with a list of reserved Rails words.

Comment: That was it. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

`rails` has the autoloading mechanism by hooking into the `const_missing` and the combination of some convention on constant naming and `autoload_paths`.

If you refer to a constant that is already predefined, either in the `ruby` standard library or the `rails`, then it will refer that constant to the already loaded one.

`Thread` is part of `ruby` standard library, which is why when you say `Thread.find_by_id(1)`, it is referring to that instead of your model.

Refer to [Thread](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Thread.html) and [Module#const_missing](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Module.html#method-i-const_missing) for more info.